# ¿Alguien sabe como activar shield en AdonisJS? Cannot call function csrfField from

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un problema con AdonisJS estoy intentando crear un formulario para enviar datos por POST, pero al momento de colocar el token me surge el siguiente error "Cannot call function csrfField from", ahora si desactivo el shield y quito la función {{ csrfField() }} el formulario corre sin ningún problema pero no quiero dejar los formularios desprotegidos.  Ya probe con la reinstalación de AdonisJS y reinstalando el shield incluyendo colocar el providers en start/app.js y colocandolo en el Kernel. ¿Alguna idea?

Así tengo el formulario

```
<form action="{{ route('libros.guardar') }}" method="post">
            {{ csrfField() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="code">Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" aria-describedby="code" placeholder="Code del libro">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" aria-describedby="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del libro">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Descriptción</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="name" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descriptción del libro"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

El app.js

```
const providers = [
  '@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider',
  '@adonisjs/framework/providers/ViewProvider',
  '@adonisjs/lucid/providers/LucidProvider',
  '@adonisjs/bodyparser/providers/BodyParserProvider',
  '@adonisjs/cors/providers/CorsProvider',
  '@adonisjs/shield/providers/ShieldProvider',
  '@adonisjs/session/providers/SessionProvider',
  '@adonisjs/auth/providers/AuthProvider'
]
```

Y el kernel.js

```
const globalMiddleware = [
  'Adonis/Middleware/BodyParser',
  'Adonis/Middleware/Session',
  'Adonis/Middleware/Shield',
  'Adonis/Middleware/AuthInit'
]
```

He visto que hay un problema con el llamado a la ruta, si la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
Route.on('/libros/agregar').render('libros.agregar')
```

Funciona, pero si hago el llamado desde el controlador no funciona:

```
Route.get('/libros/agregar', 'LibroController.agregar').as('libros.agregar')
```

Controlador:

```
'use strict'

const View = use('View')

class LibroController{
  agregar(){
    return View.render('libros.agregar')
  }
}
```

Comment: Para evitar botos negativos añade el codigo que tienes, para que puedas tener un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi con este método

```
'use strict'

class LibroController{
  agregar({view}){
    return view.render('libros.agregar')
  }
}
```

Hice el llamado del objeto view directo en la función como parámetro.